# Access last index value of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have an example dataframe (df) for 2 products:

```
                         BBG.XAMS.FUR.S               BBG.XAMS.MT.S
date                                                               
2014-10-23                 -2368.850388                    0.000000
2014-10-24                  6043.456178                    0.000000
2015-03-23                    -0.674996                   -0.674997
2015-03-24                    82.704951                   11.868748
2015-03-25                   -11.027327                   84.160210
```

Is there a way to retrieve the last index value of a dataframe only.  So in this example the date value I need retrieved is 2015-03-25?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The following gives you the last index value:

```
df.index[-1]
```

Example:

```
In [37]:

df.index[-1]
Out[37]:
Timestamp('2015-03-25 00:00:00')
```

Or you could access the index attribute of the `tail`:

```
In [40]:

df.tail(1).index[0]
Out[40]:
Timestamp('2015-03-25 00:00:00')
```

Answer (score 10):

Old post, but `df.last_valid_index()` also works.